# Exported date format not recognised in excel as date (Angular)

Tags: excel, angular, date

So I am exporting some information as excel document.
The issue I'm facing is that in Excel the actual data field containing the date is recognised as general data and I would like it to be recognised as Date.

If I double-click on the date field and click outside of it, only then it will convert it to Date.
[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ihy6U.png)
[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoSw0.png)

The first 2 fields in the second image are Date format(after double-clicking on them).

How can I make this by default so the user will have the data as Excel Date without having to do anything.

This is how I am formatting the date to my requirments:

```js
      item.documentDate = new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-US');
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do you use some library for export to excel?

Comment: I am facing a similar issue. Have you found any answers?

Comment: @ArupChaudhury yes, I did this item.startDate =  new Date(item.startDate). This will export it as proper excel Date formats. Hope it helps

Comment: @Adi I am facing same issue and I am using XLSX package in Angular 6.
Could you please help me

const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json);
  const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = { Sheets: { 'data': worksheet }, SheetNames: ['data'] };
  const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' });
  this.saveAsExcelFile(excelBuffer, excelFileName);